# How to dynamically validate an arbitrary field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For one of my Django models, I have a template for editing which is made up of input fields. However, unlike a standard form, whenever these inputs are changed, I fire off an AJAX request to save that individual field. My AJAX endpoint basically looks like this:

```
def update_field(request, mod_id, field, value, element_id):
    mod = Model.objects.get(id=mod_id)
    setattr(mod, field, value)
    mod.save()
    return json.dumps({'element_id': element_id})
```

However this is a very basic and probably naive approach. Before calling setattr and save, I'd like to validate that the input (i.e, `value`) is valid for whatever modelField `field` refers to, where `field` is a string.

Is there a way to validate this, given some input `value` and some field name on the model `field`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: I agree with @Anentropic - Create a modelform, and pass in the right `instance`. the `clean_` method would validate that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue to using any of the Model-level cleaning methods, and that is that the ValidationError raised is set up for the model in that it is keyed by field name. In my case, I am only dealing with one field, and I only want to deal with ValidationErrors from that one field. To really meet what I'm asking here (i.e, "Is there a way to validate some given some input value for some field name on some model?"), I think this is the appropriate solution:

```
def update_field(request, mod_id, field, value, element_id):
    mod = Model.objects.get(id=mod_id)
    try:
        modelfield = mod._meta.get_field(field)
        setattr(mod, field, modelfield.clean(value, mod))
    except ValidationError as e:
        # This can only be raised for errors on modelfield, not on any errors for `mod`
        return json.dumps({'errormsg': str(e)})
    mod.save()
    return json.dumps({'element_id': element_id})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform model fields validation using `clean_fields()` function. This method validates all fields on our model.

You can do something like:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model)

    ...

    def clean_fields(self):
        if self.my_field_name != 'some_valid_value': # write your logic for validity here
            raise ValidationError('Invalid value') # raise validation error
        return super(MyModel, self).clean_fields()
```

Comment: Very cool, I had forgotten that Models had their own validators and thought I'd have to do something crazy like dynamically define and instantiate a new ModelForm for whatever field I was working with or something like that. Using model.full_clean() / model.clean_fields() will be great. Thanks!